# Is there a way to put a column in a singlechildview without putting in a container with fixed height? flutter

Tags: flutter

I am making a scrollable column which consists of some texts that may contain very long strings. Hence, I would like to make it in an infinite height and scroll. Is it possible? Or if I can get a similar view please let me know how.

```dart
Scrollbar(
  controller: _scrollController,
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    controller: _scrollController,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text("test"),
        Expanded(
          child: Text("test"),
        ),
        Text("test"),
        Text("Test")
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Have you tried with SizedBox

Comment: wrap the column with a SizedBox? without setting a finite height it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about combining your `SingleChildScrollView` with `Column`s?

[image]
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _scrollController = useScrollController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Scrollbar(
            controller: _scrollController,
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.amber,
                          child: Text(
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed commodo dignissim odio, nec volutpat est molestie et. Aliquam elit mi, cursus maximus augue sed, faucibus pellentesque urna. Curabitur molestie suscipit sapien sit amet pellentesque. Curabitur mauris est, malesuada posuere cursus vitae, feugiat eu quam. In ac mauris non orci placerat scelerisque sit amet id risus. Etiam tincidunt bibendum sagittis. Vestibulum malesuada mi quis mauris convallis, sit amet tempus mauris sollicitudin. Cras ac volutpat massa, id eleifend erat. Donec eleifend, purus consectetur aliquam accumsan, sem nibh consectetur mi, sit amet fringilla sem tortor eget libero. Sed at quam at lectus mollis vulputate.'),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.purple,
                          child: Text(
                              'Vivamus sed feugiat elit. Vestibulum quis elit quis massa consectetur faucibus in id dui.'),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: Text(
                              'Aenean vitae elit quis nisi interdum cursus. Morbi fermentum bibendum justo. In vel laoreet lorem. Integer ut pulvinar lectus. Proin bibendum pulvinar mi nec pharetra. Nullam fringilla dui dignissim, porta libero in, aliquet augue. Curabitur tristique ex lacus, a hendrerit lacus sollicitudin vel.'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      child: Text('Footer'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ), // your column
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted this kind of widget in my project. Also Can I ask why you did extend the widget to Hookwidget? It works fine without extending at least in my project.

Comment: Just in case you need access to the ScrollController: `final _scrollController = useScrollController();`

Answer (score 0):

Don't really enderstand why you use a SingleChilScrollView here, a listView will do what you want:

```
Scrollbar(
      controller: _scrollController,
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      child: ListView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        children: [
          Text("test"),
          Text("test"),
          Text("test"),
          Text("Test")
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Expanded doesn't work in Listview, Ive ran it and got "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."

Comment: yes, i edited my answer, by default childrens of ListView take all the crossaxis space

Comment: Thanks but I would like the second Text to get  as much space as possible..So the 3rd, and 4th position to the bottom no matter how long the string are. I should have written more details.

Comment: Yes he will get all the space he need: https://dartpad.dev/beea6241530fa3b1a65e64ce4264884a